# Allow access to pdf files in assets/files subfolder with htaccess angular redirect all to index.html

Tags: angular, file, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change `.htaccess` actually redirect all to `index.html` for Angular 11 app run, but I have some `.pdf` files in `/assets/files/*.pdf` subfolder and I want to allow access to these files.

`assets` folder and `index.html` are in root

In my app, I share files with `href`:

Example: `pdfFileUrl = assets/files/myFile.pdf`

```
<a class="icon" [href]="pdfFileUrl" download title="Download my file">
```

Here my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/files/ // not work
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

but files are html format and do not work

Maybe there is another way, I find some think with blob but I don't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I share files with href: Example: pdfFileUrl = assets/files/myFile.pdf

You need to use a root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-path to your PDF file, not a *relative* path as shown here. Unless your URLs only consist of single path segments then when the user is at `/foo/bar` then a *relative* client-side URL of the form `assets/files/myFile.pdf` will naturally resolve to `/foo/assets/files/myFile.pdf`, which presumably does not exist so will be routed to your Angular front-controller (ie. `/index.html`).

For example:

```
href="/assets/files/myFile.pdf"
```

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets/files/ // not work
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
> ```

I assume by the presence of "// not work" that this is a line that you added? However, the very presence of that line would result in a request for `/assets/files/myFile.pdf` being routed to the Angular front-controller (the last `RewriteRule`).

You would need to remove the negation prefix (`!`) on the *CondPattern*, or just remove the `RewriteCond` directive entirely, since the first condition that checks against `-s` is already checking that the request maps to a file "of size". Or change this for a `-f` comparison, to check for even zero-size files.

The `^.*$` regex can be simplified to simply `^` and the `NC` flag is superfluous.

Your `.htaccess` file should look more like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Canonical redirect HTTP to HTTPS and non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# Prevent static resources being rewritten to Angular
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# All other requests get routed to Angular
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

And, importantly, as mentioned at the top, make sure you are linking to the root-relative URL-path in your HTML source.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's work ! I will try with absolute path and no result with my .htaccess, so thanks a lot for your answer and your explanation I need to learn more about this.
And don't forget to add read right for user on files -rw----r-- !